# NotifyPropertyChanged Doesn't work, why?

Tags: inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to call a Property with INotifyPropertyChanged from ClassB to ClassA, but this doesn't work! What am I doing wrong?

#### Class A

```
Public Class ClassA
Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements
System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.Prope rtyChanged

Protected Overridable Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal e As
System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, e)
End Sub

Private m_prop1 As String

Public Property Prop1() As String
Get
Return m_prop1 
End Get
Set(ByVal value As String)
m_prop1 = value
End Set
End Property

End Class
```

#### Class B

```
Public Class Class  B
Inherits Class A

Private m_prop2 As String

Public Property Prop2() As String
Get
Return m_prop2 
End Get
Set(ByVal value As String)
m_prop2 = value
Dim e As New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Prop1")
OnPropertyChanged(e)
End Set
End Property

End Class
```

This example works!!.

#### Class A

```
Public Class ClassA
Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements
System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.Prope rtyChanged

Protected Overridable Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal e As
System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, e)
End Sub

Private m_prop1 As String

Public Property Prop1() As String
Get
Return m_prop1 
End Get
Set(ByVal value As String)
m_prop1 = value
End Set
End Property

End Class
```

#### Class B

```
Public Class Class  B
Inherits Class A

Private m_prop2 As String

Public Property Prop2() As String
Get
Return m_prop2 
End Get
Set(ByVal value As String)
m_prop2 = value
Dim e As New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Prop3")
OnPropertyChanged(e)
End Set
End Property

Private m_prop3 As String

Public Property Prop3() As String
Get
Return m_prop3 
End Get
Set(ByVal value As String)
m_prop3 = value
End Set
End Property

End Class
```

But I want to replace that the PropertyChanged "Prop3" call "Prop1" from another class. This is possible?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Dim e As New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Prop1")
OnPropertyChanged(e)

Comment: If i debug the program it doesn't get into the property Prop1 when the Prop2 is set

Comment: Do you expect the Set of Prop1 to be executed? If so, that is not what the raising of the event does. If (and only if) something is bound to Prop1 it will likely call the Get of Prop1 when Prop2 is set. So put a breakpoint on Prop1-Get.

Comment: Yes, what I want is when something set "Prop2" it goes to Prop1-Get but this never happend. I put a breakpoint on Prop1-Get but it doesn't stop. Is like it never get into

Comment: Did you bind anything to Prop1?

Comment: yes a textblock, that's why i want to get that value, so the textblock update when the Prop2 is set

Answer (score 0):

I solve it, I create a variable m_ClassA in ClassB and then I put it as a parameter "sender" of the OnPropertyChanged method.

Class A

```
Public Class ClassA
Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements
System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.Prope rtyChanged

Protected Overridable Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(sender, e)
End Sub

Private m_prop1 As String

Public Property Prop1() As String
Get
Return m_prop1 
End Get
Set(ByVal value As String)
m_prop1 = value
End Set
End Property

End Class
```

Class B

```
Public Class ClassB
Inherits ClassA

Private m_ClassA as ClassA

Public Sub New(ByVal c as ClassA)
   m_ClassA = c
End Sub

Private m_prop2 As String

Public Property Prop2() As String
Get
Return m_prop2 
End Get
Set(ByVal value As String)
m_prop2 = value
Dim e As New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Prop1")
OnPropertyChanged(m_ClassA,e)
End Set
End Property

End Class
```